# How to find the difference between two dates in different rows for a unique combination of records

Tags: sql, oracle

For comparing dates of different columns, I used the below query, the thing is that I need to find the same for all the combinations of prod_status,pckg,lbl
below I just used for a single combination

```
SELECT p_id,trunc(eff_dt),TRUNC(end_dt),
LEAD(trunc(eff_dt),1) OVER (ORDER BY eff_dt)AS prev_eff_dt,
LEAD(TRUNC(end_dt),1) OVER (ORDER BY end_dt)AS prev_end_dt,
COALESCE(LEAD(eff_dt,1) OVER (ORDER BY eff_dt)-TRUNC(end_dt),NULL)
FROM pm
WHERE p_id IN (61) AND prod_status='8001' AND pckg='20' AND lbl='00075'
ORDER BY p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression list in the where clause based on a subquery that will return all the combinations for the id 61.

This is the query:

```
SELECT p_id,trunc(eff_dt),TRUNC(end_dt),
LEAD(trunc(eff_dt),1) OVER (ORDER BY eff_dt)AS prev_eff_dt,
LEAD(TRUNC(end_dt),1) OVER (ORDER BY end_dt)AS prev_end_dt,
COALESCE(LEAD(eff_dt,1) OVER (ORDER BY eff_dt)-TRUNC(end_dt),NULL)
FROM pm
WHERE (prod_status, pckg, lbl) IN (select prod_status, pckg, lbl
                                     from pm
                                   where p_id = '61')
ORDER BY p_id;
```

or with no id provided:

```
SELECT p_id,trunc(eff_dt),TRUNC(end_dt),
LEAD(trunc(eff_dt),1) OVER (ORDER BY eff_dt)AS prev_eff_dt,
LEAD(TRUNC(end_dt),1) OVER (ORDER BY end_dt)AS prev_end_dt,
COALESCE(LEAD(eff_dt,1) OVER (ORDER BY eff_dt)-TRUNC(end_dt),NULL)
FROM pm
WHERE (prod_status, pckg, lbl) IN (select prod_status, pckg, lbl
                                     from pm)
ORDER BY p_id;
```

Please let me know if it helped you.

Comment: thanks for the help I have added partition by in the above query u have posted now I am able to get records

Comment: @seyed yoosuf no problem, I'm happy that I've helped you :D